# Flutter with watchOS companion app error in Xcode15

Tags: flutter, watchos, xcode15, ios17

I created flutter app and attached watchOS app.

After some settings, I got the error as follows in both Xcode and Android studio run tab.

How can I resolve this error?

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Volumes/repo/cuerer/trok/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Volumes/MyProjectName/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Volumes/MyProjectName/build/ios/Debug-watchos/trok Watch App.app' to '/Volumes/MyProjectName/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Watch/trok Watch App.app'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to reorder Build Phases's tabs (In Runner Target) like below:
[image]